# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'useParams')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

Good day, I'm having problems with the latest react-router-dom v6, I still learning the new version. Please help.

```js
import React from 'react'

function Bookingscrren({match}) {
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>Booking Page</h1>
        <h1>Room id = {match.useParams.roomid}</h1>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Bookingscrren
```

Browser Output Error:
[image]

Please be kind :) I'm new

Comment: yep, im such a noob lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the right way of using `useParams`. All of these functions that begin with `use`, or react hooks, are just those, functions. That means you call them to get access to their functionality.

```
import React from 'react'

function Bookingscrren() {
const params = useParams();
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>Booking Page</h1>
        <h1>Room id = {params.roomid}</h1>

    </div>
  )
}
```

The return value of useParams is an object with parameters. You can access each one with the `.` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to this site! Use "?" operator when you navigate inside objects. I paste here the link for documentation ([Chain Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining))
Fast example: a?.b?.c

Anyway print the "match" contents and see if useParams properties there is inside.

If you want use router-dom useParams like this:

```js
import {
  ...
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

let { id } = useParams(); //This is the hook
```

Comment: I want to thank all of you my good sirs. All your solutions work I tried it. If i can only accept all your answers i would :)

Comment: Continue to work calmly. We are here for this. Consider StackOverflow when you have problems. There are tons of people who can help you out at almost any time

Answer (score 0):

By reading the name, **useParams** you can grasp this concept that you're facing a **hook**. So use `useParams` to get the route parameters.
Example:

```js
function Bookingscreen() {
  const {id} = useParams()

  return (
    <div>
        <h1>Booking Page</h1>
        <h1>Room ID = {id}</h1>

    </div>
  )
}
```